# text convert into an image

Tags: html, css

How do I convert text into an image in HTML

Thank you.

Comment: @Brock; I was almost serious too, I didn't get the question. I thought perhaps he wanted to make an 'image' out of his HTML page.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Pekka, you need some programming language in order to do that. Here is an online resource you may want to use to convert text into an image:

http://text-image.com/

Comment: Won't that convert an image to text?

Answer (score 4):

You can't generate an image in HTML. You will need the help of a programming language for that - PHP, ASP, Python, Ruby.... on the server side, or  (more unusually) JavaScript and `Canvas` on the client side.

There are many "text as image" generation scripts in the PHP world, for example, but you will need server-side PHP for those to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is some online converter called http://www.text-image.com/ which makes your task simple

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PHP code for it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

I think you want to do a capctha system. Here is a tutorial to do this.

http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Creating-a-CAPTCHA-with-PHP/